# How to import Training Data in Bluemix Retrieve and Rank Service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, retrieve-and-rank

How to import ranker training data using the Retrieve and Rank dashboard feature in Bluemix?

I have followed the following steps:

1. Imported Documents (successful)
2. Imported Questions (successful)
3. Import training data (failed: I get the following message "All exported data has already been imported into the system. There are no updates required.") But no ranker is imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "All exported data has already been imported into the system. There are no updates required." is triggered if the training data does not match the uploaded questions and documents. Hence, it is very important to make sure that the complete collections of documents and questions are imported first.